# C# Populate nested class using foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to pull back information from two separate Database calls into one object.

Consider the following classes

```
public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Status PersonStatus { get; set; }
}
```

These represent two database tables Persons and Status that are related by the StatusId in the Persons table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status](
    [StatusId] [INT] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [StatusId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Status (StatusId) )
```

Here is the procedure to get People:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetPersons
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  PersonId ,
            StatusId
    FROM    dbo.Persons
END
```

I then read the data from the `SqlDataReader`, construct a Person object, and return an `IList<Person>`. In order to populate the PersonStatus property, currently I pass the StatusId into a secondary procedure which makes another round trip to the database.

```
IList<Person> People = new List<Person>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    People.Add(new Person()
    {
        PersonId = (int)reader["PersonId"],
        //This causes the extra round trip to the database
        StatusId = new StatusDao().GetStatus((int)reader["StatusId"])
    });
}
```

`StatusDao().GetStatus()` just executes the following procedure and constructs a `Status` object.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetStatus
    @StatusId INT = NULL
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  StatusId ,
                Name
        FROM    dbo.Status
        WHERE   @StatusId IS NULL
                OR @StatusId = StatusId
    END
```

What is the proper way to populate the `PersonStatus` property? Obviously I shouldn't do an additional round trip to the database for each `Person`. Let's assume I can't edit the procedure and just add `Name` to the SQL query.

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606649/using-enum-for-a-data-layer-objects-status-in-c-sharp) question that suggested using an enumerator. That's a good option in some cases, but let's just assume that the Status data changes regularly. That makes this no longer an option.

I am not currently using an ORM.

I can't add a new Stored Procedure, nor can I edit the existing stored procedure. I'm also not allowed to use Inline SQL.

Comment: If you're using ADO.NET, why not join the two tables together and construct the object in the DataReader on the way back?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm reading a bit about the ADO.NET join and it seems like it might be a decent solution but I'm fuzzy on how to implement this in my given scenario. Can you post an example or something to get me going in the right direction?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yeah I've seen this before. I didn't know it was called ADO.NET. I'm not allowed to use inline SQL in our environment. I'll post a bit more detail in response to your answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yeah sorry about that. I honestly thought this was going to be an easy "oh you should use LINQ and here's a sample".

Comment: @Lefka I've added a LINQ solution as well; but you won't be able to do this in one call; you'll have to make the two calls you already do.  I've only somewhat linq-ified it; since under the covers LINQ does what I did anyway;  If you have ReSharper, it'll show you the LINQ version through its refactorings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a rather odd requirement of not being able to add a new Stored Procedure or Using Inline SQL; it's going to take two trips to the database no matter what (Unless, again, Status is something that can be captured in an Enum).

If you have a `Status` object and a `Person` Object and you want to put them together, you can use the following method:

```
public static List<Person> GetStatusForPerson(List<Person> people, List<Status> statuses)
{
    List<Person> peopleWithStatuses = new List<Person>();
    foreach (var p in people) 
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.PersonId = p.PersonId;
        person.Status = statuses.Where(s => s.StatusId == person.StatusId).FirstOrDefault());

        peopleWithStatuses.Add(person);
    }
    return peopleWithStatuses;
}
```

To get this information in one round-trip to the Database (for anyone who has this issue without a weird requirement):

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    string sqlText = "Select p.PersonId, ps.Name, ps.StatusId FROM Person p INNER JOIN PersonStatus ps on p.StatusID = ps.StatusId WHERE p.PersonId = @personId";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Parameters.Add("@personId", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@personId"].Value = personId;
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            var person = new Person();
            var status = new PersonStatus();
            person.PersonID = reader["PersonId"]; 
            status.StatusId = reader["StatusId"];
            status.Name = reader["Name"];
            person.Status = status;
            persons.Add(person);
        }
    }
}
return persons;
```

#### Use Enums

If `Status` is a series of integer constants (much like an `enum`) then you could simply use an `enum` and store the possible states.

If `Status` dynamically adds or removes values, then you have to resort to the normal method of pulling data back when you're not using an ORM: [A `DataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This certainly would work, but it's not really what I'm after. I'm not allowed to do inline SQL nor edit the sproc. I guess I was hoping to find a method to pull persons and statuses separately, and then join the data together. I know I can do this, but I'm not sure if there is an easy way using say LINQ (again, not going direct to the database).

Comment: @Lefka That would have been important information in your initial question.  Why can't you add a new Stored Procedure that does this join (since it's clearly information you need?)  If you want only one trip to the Database, then you have to pull the information back all at once.  The restriction of not adding a new Stored Procedure seems a bit odd.

Comment: @GeorgetStocker This solves what I was trying to do. The LINQ method was the route I was looking for. However, I did finally convince them to add a new sproc so I actually went that way anyway. Regardless, this was a good learning experience for me. Thanks for the help.